# `message-insert-signature` : Do not add the "--" prefix?

Tags: email

How can I make `message-insert-signature` not inserting the `--` prefix? If not possible, is there a another function that inserts signature without the `--` prefix?

Comment: You want the `-- ` prefix. That is *the standard* way of identifying a signature. It is what enables clients to parse a signature as a signature. Are you trying to use this for some other purpose?

Comment: @phils I normally don't have a long signature (just my name) and I would just need two new lines to separate my "signature". If this is not called a signature, how can I insert something like that, either before or after the quoted message in the case of reply?

Comment: I'd suggest using a custom function with `message-signature-setup-hook` (which runs immediately prior to `message-insert-signature`) to insert your name. You would not use the normal signature config at all in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A signature like this can be inserted using the following code:

```
        (save-excursion
          (if (not (eq message-cite-reply-position 'above))
              (message-goto-signature)
            (message-goto-body)
            (insert "\n\n")
            (message-goto-body))
          (insert "\n\n")
          (insert "MY SIGNATURE"))
```